# How to construct a Bluebird promise that returns a constant string?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

If I have something like this

```
return this.retrieveArticles(blogId).then(function(response){
    return response.articles;
  }).then(_).call("findWhere", match).then(function(article){
    return {
      "article": article
    }
  });
```

and I decide to chop the top bit off

```
    return response.articles;
  }).then(_).call("findWhere", match).then(function(article){
    return {
      "article": article
    }
  });
```

How do I do something like

```
Promise.return(articles).then(_).call("findWhere", match).then(function(article){
    return {
      "article": article
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean `Promise.resolve(_(articles).findWhere(match))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Promise.resolve(_(articles)).call("findWhere", match);
```

or

```
Promise.resolve(articles).then(_).call("findWhere", match);
```

Answer (score 1):

From `then` you can directly return value:

```
var p = someFn().then(function(){
    return 43;
});
p.then(function(val){
    console.log(val); // 42
});
```

If you're not in a chain you can use `Promise.resolve`:

```
 var p = Promise.resolve(42);

 p.then(function(val){
     console.log(val); // 42
 });
```

Most libraries offer variants of these. Another example is Bluebird - in bluebird you can use `Promise.method` to force a function to return a promise regardless of whether or not you're returning a value or a promise yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
function promiseString(str){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    return resolve(str)
  })
}

promiseString("hello world").then(function(x){
  console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: This is kind of kind of crufty.